# PHPBB <!-- IF something here OR something here -->

Tags: html, phpbb

I am trying to do a simple if statement in PHPBB and I cannot figure out or find a solution to do an "or" in an if statement. 
I have found out how to find out if a member is a part of a certain group but now I need to find if the user belongs to either this group or that group.

I have tried

```
<!-- IF S_GROUP_ID == 12 || S_GROUP_ID == 5 -->
```

and I have tried

```
<!-- IF S_GROUP_ID == 12 or S_GROUP_ID == 5 -->
```

Am I missing something or can you not do an or in the IF statement...?

Comment: Are you remembering to add `<!-- ENDIF -->` ?

Comment: <!-- ENDIF --> is included yes.

Comment: And what is the precise problem? Does it satisfy the condition when `S_GROUP_ID == 12`, but not when `S_GROUP_ID == 5`?

Comment: When I add one condition by itself it works. I need to search to see if the user belongs to at least one of the groups.

Comment: And when you add the OR condition... what is the precise problem? Does it satisfy the condition when `S_GROUP_ID == 12`, but not when `S_GROUP_ID == 5`?

Comment: I believe that the reason why it is not working is because if the user is a member of more than one group, it only is taking their default group. For example, I am a part of two groups (5 is my default and 16 is secondary) However when I put <!-- IF S_GROUP_ID == 5 --> I dont get the displayed information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial / error I have found a solution

on includes/functions.php I needed to add

```
if ( !function_exists('group_memberships') )
    {
        include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_user.'.$phpEx);
    }
    $groups = group_memberships(false,$user->data['user_id']);
    foreach ($groups as $grouprec)
    {
        $template->assign_vars(array(
        'S_GROUP_' . $grouprec['group_id'] => true
        ));
    }
```

before

```
//The following assigns all_common_variables that may be used at any point in a template.
```

and on the .html template page I needed to do this:

```
<!-- IF S_GROUP_12 || S_GROUP_5 -->
...
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try:

```
<!-- IF S_GROUP_ID == 12 -->

<!-- ELSEIF  S_GROUP_ID == 5 -->


<!-- ELSE -->

<!-- ENDIF -->
```